# Custom wrapper in simple_form: duplicated input

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I'm using the [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) in my Rails 5.2 application. Currently, I'm having a bit of a problem when using [custom wrappers](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers) around my input.

#### My wrapper

```
config.wrappers :mini_input, tag: 'div', class: 'row responsive-label', error_class: 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-12 col-md-3' do |c|
    c.use :label_input
  end
  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-12 col-md-4' do |c|
    c.use :input
  end
end
```

#### My form

```
simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
  ...
  <%= f.input :name, required: true, label: "Name", autofocus: true, wrapper: :mini_input %>
  ...
end
```

#### Expected output

```
<div class="row responsive-label">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <label ...>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <input ...>
  </div>
</div>
```

### ...Actual output

```
<div class="row responsive-label">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <label ...>
    <input ...>    <!-- This input should not be here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <input ...>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm thinking maybe there is an error in my wrapper config, I just can't locate it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by a friend of mine [in a tweet](https://twitter.com/pojomx/status/1008117953634725889), the solution was to use `label` instead of `label_input` in the wrapper configuration.

```
config.wrappers :mini_input, tag: 'div', class: 'row responsive-label', error_class: 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-12 col-md-3' do |c|
    # c.use :label_input  Wrong
    c.use :label
  end
  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-12 col-md-4' do |c|
    c.use :input
  end
end
```

Comment: I like the answer haha :P